# My Application didnt show in the Android Market, for some users

Tags: android, google-play

I am implementing twitter app in my application. For that i used:

- signpost_common.jar
- signpost-core.jars

My application was working successfully.

I upload my app in the Android Market. Here i got an issue regarding download the app. For some users able to see my app in market and some of the users not able to see the app. Regarding this i got mail from google people, because of these signpost_common.jar,signpost-core.jars got an issue.

I coudnt able to find the solution for this. Still i am trying for solution. Kindly help us for solve to this issue.

Comment: Are you sure the signpost_common is the problem? what about screen resolution and min sdk version? can you please show your manifest file?

Comment: If you 'got mail from google people' what was their concern and have you addressed it?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Copy Protection when uploading to the market?

I had issues with that in the past. Some devices couldn't see the app when I turned the Copy Protection on.

I don't think using specific jars would make your app not visible in the market, but you can try using [Acra](http://code.google.com/p/acra/) to detect what is failing in your app.